# how to get load time of any website in a file ( log the time into a file)?

Tags: browser, time, load, page-load-time

I am looking fora utility code upon  running which I can get the load time of any website we loaded and log the same load time into a file. Has somebody did this before ? How can I do it ?

Thanks,
Sanath

Answer (score 0):

Use HTMLUnit
`page.getWebResponse().getLoadTime();` will give you the page load Time in milliseconds.